# RCU in c++11 using std::shared_ptr and a little more?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency, parallel-processing

Here's some code i write to solve a problem at the server i'm working on.
Is this valid?
I've tested it, it works, but i would like some opinions on this. Thanks!

So basically its a singly_lock_free_linked_list based on the RCU concept.

```
class data_list
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION update;
    std::atomic_int64_t count;
    concurrency::concurrent_queue<std::shared_ptr<data>> to_add;
    concurrency::concurrent_queue<int> to_remove;

public:
    data_list() :head(nullptr), count(0) { InitializeCriticalSection(&update); }
    ~data_list() {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&update);

        std::shared_ptr<node> cursor = head;
        head = nullptr;
        while (1)
        {
            if (!cursor) break;
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
    }

    struct node { std::shared_ptr<data> d; std::shared_ptr<node> next; };
    std::shared_ptr<node> head;
```

//------------------------

```
    int push_front(std::shared_ptr<data> d)
    {
        to_add.push(std::move(d));
        if (!TryEnterCriticalSection(&update))
            return 0;

        int a = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            if (!to_add.try_pop(d)) break;

            std::shared_ptr<node> temp = std::make_shared<node>();
            temp->d = d;
            temp->next = head;
            while (1) { if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&head, &head, temp)) break; }

            a++;
            count++;
        }
        LeaveCriticalSection(&update);
        return a;
    }
```

//------------------------

```
    void remove(int uid)
    {
        to_remove.push(uid);
        if (!TryEnterCriticalSection(&update))
            return;

        std::shared_ptr<node> back;
        std::shared_ptr<node> front;
        while (1)
        {
            if (!to_remove.try_pop(uid)) break;

            back = nullptr;
            front = head;
            while (1)
            {
                if (!front) break;

                if (front->d->uid == uid) {

                    if (back)
                    {
                        back->next = front->next;
                        while (1) { if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&back->next, &back->next, front->next))break; }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (1) { if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&head, &head, front->next))break; }
                    }

                    count--;
                    break;
                }

                back = front;
                front = front->next;
            }

        }

        LeaveCriticalSection(&update);
    }
```

//------------------------

```
    std::shared_ptr<data> get(int uid) const
    {
        std::shared_ptr<node> temp = std::atomic_load(&head);

        while (1)
        {
            if (!temp)break;

            if (temp->d->uid == uid)
                return temp->d;

            temp = std::atomic_load(&temp->next);
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
```

//------------------------

```
    void collect(int v, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<data>> & out_collection) const
    {
        std::shared_ptr<node> temp = std::atomic_load(&head);

        while (1)
        {
            if (!temp)break;

            if (temp->d->b == v)
                out_collection.push_back(temp->d);
            temp = std::atomic_load(&temp->next);
        }
    }
```

//------------------------

```
    int64_t get_count() const
    {
        return count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
};
```

Comment: ...no opinion ?

Comment: i found a bug....

Comment: thanks for the help >.>

Comment: you should post that on codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: wow, didn't knew about that one! Thanks!